# The project is using unsupported version of Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am a beginner so I have limited skills dealing with code errors and this kind of problems. I tried to import a project to Android Studio and then this error appeared, 'The project is using unsupported version of Gradle'. please help if you know the solution and I will be thankful if you can simplify the solution for me because as I said earlier I am a beginner with limited skills.

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to download it by clicking that Red lines below. Then restart your Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the gradle version in the `build.gradle` file. It's probably on some other places to, check the config files. Also clean your project, it solves these kind of problems. (`Build > Clean project`)

Answer (score 0):

Build > Clean Project. Then Follow the instruction shown in 'Android Monitor'.

Then also if it not solve, let me know your Studio version???

Comment: android studio 2.2.2 .. which Gradle version should I switch to? When I click on build there is no clean project option!

Answer (score 0):

To change the gradle version in the build.gradle file, as shown in the fellowing picture, and then "Build > Clean project"、"Sync Project with Gradle files" or Ctrl+F9(to rebuild your project).

[image]

Comment: hope it can help you